# php glob() alternatives

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress theme that uses glob() function. THe problem is my hosting company has disabled glob(). how to modify the code so that it works using other php functions (opendir() maybe ?)

here is the code:

```
function yiw_get_tabs_path_files() {          
$theme_files_path = YIW_THEME_FUNC_DIR . 'theme-options/';
$core_files_path  = YIW_FRAMEWORK_PATH . 'theme-options/options/';

$tabs = array();

foreach ( glob( $theme_files_path . '*.php' ) as $filename ) {
    preg_match( '/(.*)-options\.(.*)/', basename( $filename ), $filename_parts );
    $tab = $filename_parts[1];

    $tabs[$tab] = $filename;
}

foreach ( glob( $core_files_path . '*.php' ) as $filename ) {
    preg_match( '/(.*)-options\.(.*)/', basename( $filename ), $filename_parts );
    $tab = $filename_parts[1];

    $tabs[$tab] = $filename;
}

return $tabs;
```

}

Comment: Do you have a good reason to believe that your host will have left the other filesystem functions enabled?

Comment: @Ibrahim: Then try running any code which calls opendir?

Comment: OK, how to implement it on the above code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the combination of [opendir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php), [readdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) and [closedir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.closedir.php) as you
suggested.

```
// open the directory
if ($handle = opendir($file_path)) {

  // iterate over the directory entries
  while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

    // match on .php extension
    if (preg_match('/\.php$/', $entry) {
      ...
    }
  }

  // close the directory
  closedir($handle);
}
```

If these too are disabled, you can try the object-oriented [Directory](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dir.php) class.